# Create a dataContract in separe file problem

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf

Hi I need to create a class for return the data in WCF service. I followed the web at [5 simple steps to create your first RESTful service](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html). However I get the error for . I searched the web and add the System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer, Would someone tell me what should do. I am using VS2015 as the tool to build it. Thanks.

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer

 <DataContract>

 Public Class Locations
    <DataMember>
    Public Property LocationName As String
    <DataMember>
    Public Property LocationID As Integer

End Class
```

Comment: Please show your error and your `<OperationContract>`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev the error message is "Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement. "

Comment: Empty line between `<DataContract>` and `Class` declaration ;(

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the error details with me?

As you know, we usually use the datacontract to transmit the complex data type which could be recognized by the client-side and server-side. so that the data could be serialized and transmitted normally between different platforms.
For the restful web service in WCF, we need to use the Webhttpbinding build the data channel and add the Webhttpbehavior to the service endpoint.
I have made a demo, wish it is useful to you.
Server-side.

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim uri As New Uri("http://localhost:900")
        Dim binding As New WebHttpBinding()
        binding.CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = True
        binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
        Using sh As New ServiceHost(GetType(MyService), uri)
            Dim se As ServiceEndpoint = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(IService), binding, uri)
            se.EndpointBehaviors.Add(New WebHttpBehavior())
            sh.Open()
            Console.WriteLine("Service is ready")

            Console.ReadLine()
            sh.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub
    <ServiceContract([Namespace]:="mydomain")>
    Public Interface IService
        <OperationContract>
        <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
        Function SayHello() As List(Of Product)
    End Interface
    Public Class MyService
        Implements IService

        Public Function SayHello() As List(Of Product) Implements IService.SayHello

            Dim result = New List(Of Product)() From {
                New Product With {
                    .Id = 1,
                    .Name = "Apple"
                },
                New Product With {
                    .Id = 2,
                    .Name = "Pear"
                }
            }
            Return result
        End Function
    End Class
    <DataContract([Namespace]:="mydomain")>
    Public Class Product
        <DataMember>
        Public Property Id() As Integer
        <DataMember>
        Public Property Name() As String
    End Class

End Module
```

Client.

```
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://10.157.18.188:900/sayhello",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    success:function(d){
     $.each(d,function(i,o){
         console.log(o.Id);
         console.log(o.Name);
     })
    }
})
```

})

Result.
[image]
Here is an official sample

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-basic-wcf-web-http-service

Comment: the message is "Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement"

Comment: Please remove empty lines between dataContract and class definition statements.